# Unable to start locals mysql server using DVWA,apache2

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm unable to start a local server on my kali virtual machine using DVWA,apache2.
The error message shown in DVWA is -

```
Could not connect to the MySQL service.
Please check the config file.
```

Contents of  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf  (to see all contents please reply)are-

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
feedback        = On
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

The output of the command $service mysql status is-

```
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: 2017-03-24 19:24:21 140110264951360 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: 2017-03-24 19:24:21 140110264951360 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: 2017-03-24 19:24:21 140109647177472 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not y
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: 2017-03-24 19:24:21 140110264951360 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::1'.
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: 2017-03-24 19:24:21 140110264951360 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connecti
Mar 24 19:24:21 kali mysqld[22936]: Version: '10.1.21-MariaDB-5'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306
Mar 24 19:24:22 kali mysql[22764]: Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
Mar 24 19:24:22 kali systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Mar 24 19:24:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[23000]: WARNING: mysql.user contains 3 root accounts without password
Mar 24 19:24:22 kali /etc/mysql/debian-start[23001]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables and aria-recover
```

The first six lines are in red colour.

The output of command $netstat -vln is-

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN   

netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF INET (sctp)' on this system.
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7          
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17372    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1133
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17413    /run/user/0/keyring/ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17130    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14829    /tmp/.ICE-unix/769
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14947    /tmp/.X11-unix/X1024
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17280    /tmp/ssh-dTUA0HGqFfRr/agent.1133
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17373    /tmp/.ICE-unix/1133
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17442    /run/user/0/keyring/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17129    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     15398    /run/user/132/pulse/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11560    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11563    /var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11566    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14828    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/769
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13592    @/tmp/dbus-LvFbrf6k
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13589    @/tmp/dbus-XyEHDwXr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14677    /run/user/132/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14684    /run/user/132/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14687    /run/user/132/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14689    /run/user/132/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14691    /run/user/132/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14693    /run/user/132/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14695    /run/user/132/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14956    /run/user/132/wayland-0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17116    @/tmp/dbus-SH8jFiyf
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     108931   /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9119     /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13593    @/tmp/dbus-oibNPS4f
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13590    @/tmp/dbus-aFHv8BHv
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9131     /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9139     /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9143     /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9146     /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16320    @/tmp/dbus-qF1bHGdD5y
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17098    /run/user/0/keyring/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14946    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X1024
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17117    @/tmp/dbus-FODO2EfC
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     9177     /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16090    /run/user/0/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16095    /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16098    /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16100    /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16102    /run/user/0/bus
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16106    /run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16108    /run/user/0/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     14983    @/tmp/dbus-ceiJ2zXVDW
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     57848    /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp
netstat: no support for `AF IPX' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF AX25' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF X25' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF NETROM' on this system.
netstat: no support for `AF ROSE' on this system.
```

The contents of  /var/www/html/dvwa/config/config.inc.php  are-

```
<?php

# If you are having problems connecting to the MySQL database and all of the va$
# try changing the 'db_server' variable from localhost to 127.0.0.1. Fixes a pr$
#   Thanks to @digininja for the fix.

# Database management system to use
$DBMS = 'MySQL';
#$DBMS = 'PGSQL'; // Currently disabled

# Database variables
#   WARNING: The database specified under db_database WILL BE ENTIRELY DELETED $
#   Please use a database dedicated to DVWA.
$_DVWA = array();
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ]   = 'localhost';
$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';
$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';

# ReCAPTCHA settings
#   Used for the 'Insecure CAPTCHA' module
#   You'll need to generate your own keys at: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/$
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = 'lecaptcha';
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = 'lecaptcha';

# Default security level
#   Default value for the secuirty level with each session.
#   The default is 'impossible'. You may wish to set this to either 'low', 'med$
$_DVWA[ 'default_security_level' ] = 'impossible';

# Default PHPIDS status
#   PHPIDS status with each session.
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'enabled' or 'disa$
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_level' ] = 'disabled';

# Verbose PHPIDS messages
#   Enabling this will show why the WAF blocked the request on the blocked requ$
#   The default is 'disabled'. You can set this to be either 'true' or 'false'.
$_DVWA[ 'default_phpids_verbose' ] = 'false';

?>
```

I've searched a lot about this issue but am unable to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/ethicalhack3r/DVWA/issues/240

That is, just add:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

before the "service mysql start" in the `main.sh` file.

Cheers